# Bitmap.recycle() Calling it after drawing

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, out-of-memory

I am having a problem. I have a post draw listener where I draw a scaled version of a bitmap. The problem stems from the fact that I tend to do some scaling every time a zoom happens (zoom in scale up, zoom out scale down). The problem is I am not able to recycle the bitmap because when I try to do so after drawing

```
canvas.draw(scaledbitmap,0,0,null);
scaledBitmap.recycle()
```

i get the Canvas canot draw recycled bitmap exception

Does anyone know how I would go about recycling a bitmap after I am done with it so that another can be scaled afterwards and I don't get the OutOfMemoryException crash.

Some Code to show you exactly how I am using it:

```
private SpenDrawListener mPosteDrawListener = new SpenDrawListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, float x, float y, float ratio,
            float frameStartX, float frameStartY, RectF updateRect) {
            if(mLineDrawingBitmap == null)
                mLineDrawingBitmap = loadLineDrawingBitmap(mLineDrawingFileName);

            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mLineDrawingBitmap, (int)(mLineDrawingBitmap.getWidth() * ratio), (int)(mLineDrawingBitmap.getHeight() * ratio), true);
            /*
            float pointX = (mScreenRect.width() - bm.getWidth()) / 2;
            float pointY = mScreenRect.height() / 2 - bm.getHeight();
            */
            float pointX = frameStartX - (x * ratio);
            float pointY = frameStartY - (y * ratio);

            //canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0,null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bm, pointX, pointY, null);

            //bm.recycle();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of trial and error I have figured out how to scale nicely AND not crash the app with an OutOfMemoryException: Below is the code for drawing and scaling at runtime with no crash (as long as the image is not too large when decoded). I will use my own PostDrawListener but I believe it can be used anywhere with minor modification

```
private SpenDrawListener mPosteDrawListener = new SpenDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, float x, float y, float ratio,
        float frameStartX, float frameStartY, RectF updateRect) {
        if(mLineDrawingBitmap == null)
                mLineDrawingBitmap = loadLineDrawingBitmap(mLineDrawingFileName);

        float pointX = frameStartX - (x * ratio);
        float pointY = frameStartY - (y * ratio);

        //Create a new Matrix
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        //Use any scaling ratio you want
        m.postScale(ratio, ratio);
        //Use any translation you want
        m.postTranslate(pointX, pointY);
        //when using below call you will not be creating a new bitmap, just
        //using the original with runtime modifications    
        canvas.drawBitmap(mLineDrawingBitmap, m, null);

    }
};
```